# Render object with vertex color using bpy or convert vertex color to texture

Tags: python-3.x, blender, bpy

I tried to render an object (.obj & .ply - both doesn't work) using bpy(`version 2.93.1`), but they were grey (without color), despite that they had vertex color.

[how object looks like in meshlab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4gNR.png)

```
import bpy
import os


bpy.ops.object.select_by_type(type='MESH')
bpy.ops.object.delete()

file_loc = '../from-obj-to-photos/objects/glass.ply'
# imported_object = bpy.ops.import_scene.obj(filepath=file_loc, split_mode="OFF")
bpy.ops.import_mesh.ply(filepath=file_loc)
obj_object = bpy.context.selected_objects[0]
print('Imported name:', obj_object.name)

bpy.context.scene.render.filepath = '~/Desktop/photos/img.jpg'
bpy.context.scene.render.engine = 'CYCLES'
bpy.ops.render.render('INVOKE_DEFAULT', write_still=True)
```

After applying this code I got a grey glass like this: [grey glass](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tkLE1.jpg)

Then I found out how to fix this, and my final code looks like this:

```
import bpy

bpy.ops.object.select_by_type(type='MESH')
bpy.ops.object.delete()

file_loc = '../from-obj-to-photos/objects/glass.ply'
# imported_object = bpy.ops.import_scene.obj(filepath=file_loc, split_mode="OFF")
bpy.ops.import_mesh.ply(filepath=file_loc)
obj_object = bpy.context.selected_objects[0]
print('Imported name:', obj_object.name)


bpy.data.objects["glass"].select_set(True)
bpy.ops.paint.vertex_paint_toggle()

#bpy.context.area.ui_type = 'ShaderNodeTree'

#bpy.ops.material.new()

mat = bpy.data.materials.get("Material")


if mat:
    mat.node_tree.nodes.new("ShaderNodeVertexColor")
    mat.node_tree.links.new(mat.node_tree.nodes[2].outputs['Color'], mat.node_tree.nodes[1].inputs['Base Color'])


bpy.context.scene.render.filepath = '~/Desktop/photos/img.jpg'
bpy.context.scene.render.engine = 'CYCLES'
bpy.ops.render.render('INVOKE_DEFAULT', write_still=True)
```

But it shows an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<blender_console>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 'bpy_prop_collection[key]: key "Base Color" not found'
```

And to fix it, I have to open Shader Editor, tap the button [`browse material to be linked`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Di2S5.png) and choose `Material`.

After executing code the glass is colored ([result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJCxP.jpg)). But I don't know how to automate processes from previous paragraph.

Also, i guess that converting vertex color to texture might fix this issue, but I didn't find anywhere how to do it using python.

I would be really grateful if anyone helps me with this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution! if you paste`if len(bpy.context.active_object.data.materials) == 0: bpy.context.active_object.data.materials.append(bpy.data.materials['Material']) else: bpy.context.active_object.data.materials[0] = bpy.data.materials['Material']`

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution! If you paste

```
if len(bpy.context.active_object.data.materials) == 0:
    bpy.context.active_object.data.materials.append(bpy.data.materials['Material'])
else:
    bpy.context.active_object.data.materials[0] = bpy.data.materials['Material']
```

before **if statement**, everything will work correctly